# How to make input type file send empty string instead of null when no file is selected

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, input

when there is file selected then it send it's file, but when nothing is selected I want it to send empty string, or anything empty so I can still recognize it.

I need this, when in case I want to edit some array data with file, just say there are 2 datas like : data 1 => `$_POST['name'][$i], $_FILES['file'][$i]`, data 2 => `$_POST['name'][$i], $_FILES['file'][$i]`

if all 2 datas selected new file then it's ok, but how if only one file is selected, just say it's index `[1]`. when I do looping to get all data then it's not match to length of `$_POST['name']`, and I don't know the selected file comes from which index.

Why I need it send empty instead null is so `$_FILES['file']` length can match the length of `$_POST['name']`. So I can do looping correctly.

> Note : Sorry for my bad explanation, I hope you guys can get it

Answer (score 0):

Just while looping put isset function on name and file so it will not take it on consider if it's null

```
if (isset($_POST['name'][$i])){
...
}
if (isset($_FILES['file'][$i])){
...
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: what I want to achive is, it return empty instead of null, cause I already know that it's null. So imagine i have 5 $_POST['name'] and 5 $_POST['file'], but the not null file is only 3,  so when you send it via form, the backend will receive 5 $_POST['name'] and 3 $_FILES['file'], I want it to receive 5 $_POST['name'] and 5 $_FILES['file']

Comment: can you please post a sample code that will help undrestanding what you really want

Answer (score 0):

I think this is bad practice do it like that.
If you want to do like this, you have to set all `$_FILES['file']` with default value to create the `$_FILES` array. So, you can get all 5 `$_FILES` and in the loop you can recognize empty file with that default value.
Other thing you can do is, give `$_FILES` to different name like following,

```
$_FILES['file1'];
$_FILES['file2'];
...
$_FILES['file5'];
```

Loop will be default,

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ...
```

Get the file with,

```
$file = $_FILES['file' . $i];
```

Checking empty file condition,

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file' . $i]['name'])) { ...
```

I think this way better than setting default values. Hope it helps.

Edit:
Don't use the `isset`, because it `$_FILES` always set with `NULL`. Best is check name empty or not.

Comment: so how to make a default value for input type file ?